# Perl sort array creates new element if element being referenced

Tags: sorting, perl, reference

I have an array of strings, would like to record its original order in another array by referencing its elements, then I sort the array of strings, it creates new element in this array rather than the original element.

```
my @item = qw/zz xx/;
my @order;

foreach (@item) {
    push @order, \$_;
}

print $item[0] . " " . \$item[0] . "\n";
print $item[1] . " " . \$item[1] . "\n";

@item = sort {$a cmp $b} @item;

print $item[0] . " " . \$item[0] . "\n";
print $item[1] . " " . \$item[1] . "\n";
```

**Result:**

```
zz SCALAR(0x5618ffd27220)
xx SCALAR(0x5618ffd273e8)
xx SCALAR(0x5618ffd46668)
zz SCALAR(0x5618ffd46698)
```

If I comment out the reference block, then the outcome return to expected result. So can anyone explain how referencing the element would affect the result of "sort".

**Expected Result:**

```
zz SCALAR(0x5618ffd27220)
xx SCALAR(0x5618ffd273e8)
xx SCALAR(0x5618ffd273e8)
zz SCALAR(0x5618ffd27220)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. In fact yours seems to contradict the [Perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort), which says _`sort` returns aliases into the original list…_.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. Can you add details of your Perl version to the question please?

Comment: *returns aliases* does suggest it returns values with new pointers  instead of the original, but also `@foo = sort @foo` is supposed to sort in place instead of returning a new list which sounds like it shouldn't be allocating new values...

Comment: I found it behave differently between perl version 5.22 & 5.26, tested on some online perl, can be reproduced from version 5.26 and onward.

Comment: My results, all with a custom-built default Perl running on an Intel dual-core i5 Mac, macOS Ventura 13.4 (Darwin 22.5.0): 5.22.4 OK; 5.24.4 OK; 5.26.0 NOT OK; 5.26.3 NOT OK; 5.28.3 NOT OK; 5.30.3 NOT OK; 5.32.1 NOT OK; 5.34.1 NOT OK; 5.36.1 NOT OK; 5.37.11 NOT OK. The last strongly suggests that 5.38.0 will not be ok either.

Comment: You have OK and NOT OK backwards. 5.26 fixed the bug which existed up until then.

Comment: My bad. By "OK" I meant "preserves references," and by "NOT OK" I meant "does not preserve references." But as your reply makes clear, these mean, respectively, "buggy" and "not buggy."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning a scalar to an element of an array makes a copy of the scalar.

For example,

```perl
use v5.14;
my $x = 123;
say \$x;
my @a = $x;
say \$a[0];
```

outputs something like

```
SCALAR(0x55dd65bf0e18)
SCALAR(0x55dd65bc14b8)
```

So the result you get is the result you should expect.

---

But what about

```perl
my @c = qw( l k j );
say for \( @c );
@c = sort @c;
say for \( @c );
```

```
SCALAR(0x55c396e0d4b8)
SCALAR(0x55c396e0d4e8)
SCALAR(0x55c396e0d680)
SCALAR(0x55c396e0d680)
SCALAR(0x55c396e0d4e8)
SCALAR(0x55c396e0d4b8)
```

`sort` has an optimization for the case when an array is being sorted, and the results are assigned to the same array (e.g. `@a = sort @a;`). In these situations, it performs an in-place sort. It simply moves the C pointers around without creating any new scalars.

As long as nothing references the values of the array, it is safe to do so.

---

But what about

```perl
my @c = qw( l k j );
my @r = \( @c );
say for \( @c );
@c = sort @c;
say for \( @c );
```

```
SCALAR(0x55abf592e4b8)
SCALAR(0x55abf592e4e8)
SCALAR(0x55abf592e680)
SCALAR(0x55abf595d660)
SCALAR(0x55abf595d648)
SCALAR(0x55abf595d6f0)
```

An optimization is only correct if it's transparent. An optimization that causes code to behave differently than unoptimized code is buggy. In other words, `sort` should work the same with or without the optimization. Which means that `sort` needs to make copies of values referenced by something other the array even when the optimization is used.

It can get away from doing this if nothing else references the array values, but that's not the case here.

---

Note that versions of Perl before 5.26 were buggy. These programs should output the same, but they don't:

```
$ perl5.24t -le'@c = qw(l k j); $d = \$c[2]; @c = @e = sort @c; $$d = "X"; print @c'
jkl

$ perl5.24t -le'@c = qw(l k j); $d = \$c[2]; @c =      sort @c; $$d = "X"; print @c'
Xkl
```

This was [fixed](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/45c198c1bc981a507ab719edbd292922a896a397) in 5.26. Since then, the sort is still done in-place, but a copy of every value with a refcount greater than one is made first.

```
$ perl5.26t -le'@c = qw(l k j); $d = \$c[2]; @c = @e = sort @c; $$d = "X"; print @c'
jkl

$ perl5.26t -le'@c = qw(l k j); $d = \$c[2]; @c =      sort @c; $$d = "X"; print @c'
jkl
```

Comment: I'm confused, but isn't it quite dangerous that the result of in-place sort depends on refcount? Since I may someday modifying my code and added a reference to an element in an array, then it will mess up everything.

Comment: No, it's the opposite. Taking a reference would "mess up everything" without the fix. (See the second-last snippet block, where the output is `jkX`.) The fix makes `sort @c` work the same with and without the optimization. (See the last snippet block.)

Comment: Imagine if you did `@item = qw( aa bb );` instead of `@item = sort ...;` You get the same result. As you should. If you assign new things to an array, the array no longer contains the same scalars.

Comment: If you think the current implementation is buggy (i.e. can "mess up everything"), show me a program that works differently (in 5.26+) for `@a = sort @a;` and for `{ @a = my @tmp = sort @a; }`. (Keep in mind that a new scalar can reuse the same address as an old scalar, so just printing addresses is not enough.)

Comment: Yes, I can see there is a problem for ` my @tmp = @c = sort @c; ` in version <5.26, needed to break it into ` @c = sort @c; my @tmp = @c; ` to make it work. I won't say the current implementation is buggy, just wanted to learn more about its behaviour, and I eventually modified my program to sort the array of referenced elements rather than the original array, which make more sense. Thank you very much for those explanations.

Comment: Re "*I can see there is a problem for `my @tmp = @c = sort @c;` in version <5.26,*", More specifically, there's a bug with `@c = sort @c;` (with or without the leading `my @tmp =`) in version <5.26 if you have external reference to values of `@c`.

Comment: Re "*needed to break it into `@c = sort @c; my @tmp = @c;` to make it work.*", No, that wouldn't fix the problem. `my @tmp = sort @c; @c = @tmp;` aka `@c = my @tmp = sort @c;` would

Comment: Re "*I won't say the current implementation is buggy*", Cause it's not. The old implementation was, and it was fixed in 5.26.